# MVC 4 DropdownListfor error

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
      ViewBag.roleList = DALUser.GetRoleList();
      ViewBag.stateList = DALUser.GetStateList();
      return View();
    }

<li>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.role)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.role, new SelectList(ViewBag.roleList, "Select Role"))
</li>
```

**It causes**

> "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: items". roleList and stateList
>   are just string List

Anyone has an idea on this?

Comment: Try this: new SelectList((List<string>ViewBag.roleList, "Select Role"))

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you will see that error when you give the `SelectList` constructor a null value. You need to put a breakpoint on `ViewBag.roleList = DALUser.GetRoleList();` and verify that something other than `null` is being returned. Remember, the default value of an `IList` object is `null`.

Comment: Well, list items show up on the dropdownlist properly. When I click submit button, it causes an error.

Comment: _"When I click submit button, it causes an error."_ - do you re-fill the ViewBag in the `HttpPost` action?

Comment: @user1713153 As CodeCaster alludes to, collections **aren't** persisted across HTTP requests unless you "hide" then in the form somewhere (that's how the `ViewState` mechanism works). Remember, MVC isn't WebForms - you need to recreate any data that isn't bound to an input element. `DropDownList` binds to a "selected value" property, not the collection.